# Error in loading bootstrap on Python Flask

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap, flask

I have the following code app.py in flask.

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap

app = Flask(__name__)
Bootstrap(app)


@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template("home.html")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Where home.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Cheppers DevOps Challeng | Home</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    {% extends "template.html" %}
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

The template has a simple bootstrap code that runs perfectly.

I would like to run bootstrap over all my html pages, where I created a template webpage for the navbar (template.html)

I have got the following error:

```
  File "/Volumes/Data/final/web_cheppers/app.py", line 15, in home
    return render_template("home.html")
  File "/Volumes/Data/final/web_cheppers/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 140, in render_template
    ctx.app,
  File "/Volumes/Data/final/web_cheppers/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 120, in _render
    rv = template.render(context)
  File "/Volumes/Data/final/web_cheppers/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/asyncsupport.py", line 76, in render
    return original_render(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Volumes/Data/final/web_cheppers/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1008, in render
    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
  File "/Volumes/Data/final/web_cheppers/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 780, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Volumes/Data/final/web_cheppers/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/_compat.py", line 37, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/Volumes/Data/final/web_cheppers/templates/home.html", line 8, in top-level template code
    {% extends "template.html" %}
  File "/Volumes/Data/final/web_cheppers/templates/template.html", line 47, in top-level template code
    {% block scripts %}
  File "/Volumes/Data/final/web_cheppers/templates/template.html", line 49, in block "scripts"
    {{ bootstrap.load_js() }}
  File "/Volumes/Data/final/web_cheppers/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 430, in getattr
    return getattr(obj, attribute)
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'bootstrap' is undefined
```

I have tried to uninstall and install Flask-Bootstrap, but still nothing.

Comment: Looks like somewhere you're calling 'bootstrap' in of your html files. Perhaps in template.html?

Answer (score 0):

I have found it what was wrong.

Obviously, I was importing wrong library of Flask-Bootstrap which is unidentified by pycharm. I found the one which is working Bootstrap-Flask on 1.1.0 version